# How can I connect to a USB Device from a Kubernetes Service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I need to connect to a PCSC card reader on Ubuntu 18.04 box. To run my program locally I needed to install pcsc-lite and also device driver.  It runs fine locally but now to run this same program as a service in Kubernetes? What are the steps for doing this? Do I need to mount the drivers? All nodes will already have the driver installed. But what about the creation of the container and the deployment descriptor?

Comment: Why are you using PCSC card reader? can you change this to use directlly a folder? the easy way should be to have the information o a folder and mount it as a volume without worring if is a card reader or other kind of device.

Comment: Can you explain you question in more details? Your application needs this USB device to run like a Hardlock? Kubernetes is a system for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications. It can be pointless, because you'll not be able to scale up your cluster.
If you want to be able to have access to your physical device this can be an answer for you: [# [Kubernetes node Device port (USB) mapping to POD? Or Swarm service --device mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697985/kubernetes-node-device-port-usb-mapping-to-pod-or-swarm-service-device-mapp)

Comment: So the card reader I have is a charter reader/ not block device. It needs to run on a few nodes for HA and I cannot have the mount point change every time the device is reattached to the node.

Comment: @AverageBear did you try solution suggested in the previous comment?

Comment: Its a character based reader and not a block storage device.

Comment: @wolmi well its a card reader and character based so not sure how this could be done.  Another issue is that on different machines the dev/location varies when the card reader is plugged in ..

Comment: so it looks like i need to load the drivers into the container ...